# iPhone Upload video to youtube app using GData framework

Tags: iphone, youtube-api

I want to upload video from my app to the youtube. I am using the example YoutubeTest for this purpose. I have set the developer key and client Id for my app. Now when trying to upload the video using example source code, it shows an error which is:

> 2012-03-19 10:51:07.947 YouTubeTest[539:f803] serviceBase: objectFetcher: failedWithStatus:400 data:
>   2012-03-19 10:51:07.985 YouTubeTest[539:f803] Error: Error Domain=com.google.GDataServiceDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GDataServiceDomain error 400.)" UserInfo=0x6c49e50 {}

Has anyone successfully implemented the GData to upload videos to youtube from the iphone app. Can anyone give me the example source code.

Comment: How to get client-id please give me link for that.

Comment: @MohitGupta client id will be the name of your app by which you are registering your application and getting your developer key.

Comment: But it shows the error NOT linked Youtube account..please if you have  working Code the provide me..It's my humble request to you.@coder1010

Comment: did you register your app and generated the developer key? And give me your mail id so that i can send you the demo code

Comment: my email is mohit.gupta7860@rediffmail.com thanks a lot..

Comment: try this: http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/youtube-ios-framework/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ofcourse many had successfully implemented it ... hmmm try this link http://urinieto.com/category/google/ follow instructions line by line.

Not Sure y you are getting this error. Follow above instructions if problem still persists i will help you out .

Cheers

Comment: Yes i have followed each step as explained in the tutorial. Still the error persists.Not getting any idea where i am wrong. Even i tried to change the account type to GOOGLE from HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE but still failing. Dont know what to do.

Comment: Error code 400 is a bad request "Invalid request URI or header, or unsupported nonstandard parameter." Which basicly means you have misformatted your request. http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html #HTTPStatusCodes Link to explain all error codes.

Comment: Hey are you able to upload ur video using YOUTUBE sample code to ur account..?

Comment: no as soon as i login using my google email id and password and click the upload the Error alert box arrives.

Comment: When i NSLogged my post string i found that character @ in email id is printed as %40. Is this the problem?
Here is my post string :
POST STRING--Email=chxxxx.agxxx%40gmail.com&Passwd=chhxxxxxx&source=com.yourcompany.YouTubeTest-1.0&service=youtube&accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE

Comment: Damn you dont have enough reputation for chat application... %40 is percent encode for @ .. its fine there...

Comment: - (IBAction)uploadPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *devKey = [mDeveloperKeyField text];
    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
    [service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:devKey];
    NSString *username = [mUsernameField text];
    NSString *clientID = [mClientIDField text];
    NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:username
                                                             clientID:clientID];

Comment: NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YouTubeTest" ofType:@"m4v"]; 
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *filename = [path lastPathComponent];
    NSString *titleStr = [mTitleField text];
    GDataMediaTitle *title = [GDataMediaTitle textConstructWithString:titleStr];
    NSString *categoryStr = [mCategoryField text];
    GDataMediaCategory *category = [GDataMediaCategory mediaCategoryWithString:categoryStr];
    [category setScheme:kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory];
    NSString *descStr = [mDescriptionField text];

Comment: NSString *keywordsStr = [mKeywordsField text];
    GDataMediaKeywords *keywords = [GDataMediaKeywords keywordsWithString:keywordsStr];
    BOOL isPrivate = mIsPrivate;
    GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
    [mediaGroup setMediaTitle:title];
    [mediaGroup setMediaDescription:desc];
    [mediaGroup addMediaCategory:category];
    [mediaGroup setMediaKeywords:keywords];
  [mediaGroup setIsPrivate:isPrivate];
    NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:path                                             defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

Comment: GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;
entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup data:data slug:filename];
SEL progressSel = @selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
    [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];
    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
    ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                      forFeedURL:url
                                        delegate:self
                               didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
    [self setUploadTicket:ticket];

Comment: this is the upload button code. please give me you mail id i l give you the full source code to check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9038/discussion-between-tornado-and-chhaya-ahuja)

Comment: Please put the full solution in the body of the answer.

Comment: Will keep this in Mind next time But why r u down voting my answer other people might think it as wrong ... link provided there is quite helpful ...@BilltheLizard

Comment: @Tornado I am facing same error while uploading Video on youTube. I am  using this code: http://urinieto.com/iPhone/YouTubeTest.zip               and i have made following changes only:   #define DEVELOPER_KEY @"AI39si7QYMm5aKipJT62OtFnonK2TBvOkib3EMRYBIzDXAbuTFqvOZAfnEDnco1d-Z_grLggzogsxpzrr8DuaAfeK6uVtDYMlg"
#define CLIENT_ID @"YOURCLIENTID!!!!!"

Comment: k first check ur client id its basically ur product name u registered in code.google.com in ur account . secondly the username u r using to upload video should not be ur email id it should be ur nick name for that youtube account .. try this if still problem persists notify me ..

Comment: How can i get client-id for all process please tell me..I am waiting for positive response.

Comment: i have successFully posted video on youtube , now i want url for my posted video , can i have it ?? please help

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue with YouTubeTest app. here is the code for request:

```
(IBAction)uploadPressed:(id)sender {

    NSString *devKey = [mDeveloperKeyField text];

    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
    [service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:devKey];

    NSString *username = [mUsernameField text];
    NSString *clientID = [mClientIDField text];

    NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:username
                                                             clientID:clientID];

    // load the file data
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YouTubeTest" ofType:@"m4v"]; 
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *filename = [path lastPathComponent];

    // gather all the metadata needed for the mediaGroup
    NSString *titleStr = [mTitleField text];
    GDataMediaTitle *title = [GDataMediaTitle textConstructWithString:titleStr];

    NSString *categoryStr = [mCategoryField text];
    GDataMediaCategory *category = [GDataMediaCategory mediaCategoryWithString:categoryStr];
    [category setScheme:kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory];

    NSString *descStr = [mDescriptionField text];
    GDataMediaDescription *desc = [GDataMediaDescription textConstructWithString:descStr];

    NSString *keywordsStr = [mKeywordsField text];
    GDataMediaKeywords *keywords = [GDataMediaKeywords keywordsWithString:keywordsStr];

    BOOL isPrivate = mIsPrivate;

    GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
    [mediaGroup setMediaTitle:title];
    [mediaGroup setMediaDescription:desc];
    [mediaGroup addMediaCategory:category];
    [mediaGroup setMediaKeywords:keywords];
    [mediaGroup setIsPrivate:isPrivate];

    NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:path
                                               defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

    // create the upload entry with the mediaGroup and the file data
    GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;
    entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                          data:data
                                                      MIMEType:mimeType
                                                          slug:filename];

    SEL progressSel = @selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
    [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];

    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
    ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                      forFeedURL:url
                                        delegate:self
                               didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];

    [self setUploadTicket:ticket];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem. The error info in your case is not enough. But if you print out the HTTPURLResponse from the server , it will help to spot the error. In my case keywords length was too long.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error. But I did find a solution through trial and error :)

Actually as Youtube itself states

[image]

You don't need to provide Client_Id anymore. Please remove it.

But the actual problem was with the login credentials. API was returning error response when i login as "xyz@gmail.com". It started working when i provided just the username without domain "xyz".

Hope this helps!