# error on uploading Video to Youtube failedWithStatus:400

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Upload video to youtube app using GData framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765394/iphone-upload-video-to-youtube-app-using-gdata-framework)

getting error on Uploading Video to Youtube failedWithStatus:400 data, i added devloper key and clint id  but i am not able to find the problem so plzz help me out.

Comment: how to send request ?show some code. may be there are some problem in request because 400 error means:the request is incorrect.